# How can I precompile SCSS in SvelteKit?

Tags: sass, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to add SCSS to my SvelteKit app. It works within components; however, when I convert the default `app.css` into a scss file and update the import from the base application, the page loads with a FOUC.

```
<script context="module">
    import '../app.scss'; // Changed from .css
</script>
```

Is there a way to make SvelteKit precompile the styles and inline them the same way it does standard CSS files?

Comment: Just an FYI - as of Sveltekit 1.0, imported scss can be precompiled and will do so with the default skeleton project.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a SCSS import instead:

```
<style lang="scss" global>
    @import '../app';
</style>
```

The `global` keyword is necessary if you're importing a global layout stylesheet. If you leave it out, styles that are imported will be scoped to your component.

Comment: Remember to install sass with your package manager of choice.
I use pnpm: `pnpm i --save-dev sass`.